# Quel est le sens de « il en va » ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

> Après avoir observé le sort réservé à Saddam Hussein en Irak et à
>   Mouammar Kadhafi en Libye, pays qui n’étaient pas dotés de l’arme
>   nucléaire, le régime nord-coréen considère que cette technologie est
>   la clé de sa survie. De son côté, la Chine juge qu’[**il en va**](http://www.lemonde.fr/asie-pacifique/article/2017/04/15/la-coree-du-nord-menace-les-etats-unis-de-guerre-nucleaire_5111763_3216.html)
>   de son intérêt stratégique de maintenir en vie cet Etat tampon.
>   Environ 28 500 soldats américains sont stationnés en Corée du Sud, et
>   il n’est pas question pour Pékin qu’une réunification sur le modèle du
>   Sud – comme elle s’est faite en Allemagne sur le modèle de l’Ouest –
>   permette à ces troupes de s’installer à sa propre frontière.

Je sais que l'expression **il en va de même pour** signifie, selon *Larousse*, [**la situation est la même pour**](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aller/2359/locution).

Mais je ne peux pas comprendre ce que cette expression, **il en va**, signifie ; et surtout comment je peux la traduire en anglais (je ne l'ai trouvé traduite nulle part).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pour moi il s'agit de la part de l'auteur de l'article d'une confusion entre *il en va* et *il y va*.

Regardons les définitions des deux expressions dans le Wiktionnaire :

> 13. Joint à l'adverbe **y** et employé comme verbe impersonnel, sert à marquer ce qui est mis en cause, de quoi il s’agit.
>
>     - *Songez qu’il y va de votre fortune.*
> 14. Joint à l'adverbe **en** et employé comme verbe impersonnel, sert à exprimer une comparaison. Il en va de même / ainsi / tout autrement pour suivi d'un complément signifie Il en est de même / tout autrement pour, La même chose s'applique à / ne s'applique pas à.
>
>     - *Le prix du pétrole augmente ; il en va de même pour le prix du gaz.*

Dans l'article cité je comprends qu'**il y va** (il s'agit de son intérêt/ il est de son intérêt) de l'intérêt stratégique de la Chine de ...

Apparemment cette confusion entre ces deux expressions impersonnelles à partir du verbe *aller* n'est pas rare puisqu'elle suscite des articles sur des blogs consacrés à la langue française.

Sur [Parler français](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/il-en-va-il-y-va-a20557904) :
**Il en va / Il y va**

> Les locutions impersonnelles construites avec le verbe **aller** peuvent poser quelques problèmes de construction.
>   Ainsi se gardera-t-on de toute confusion entre **il en va (de même, ainsi, autrement...) de** (ou **pour**), qui marque une comparaison et est synonyme de « il en est (de même pour telle personne) », et **il y va (de)**, qui exprime un enjeu et signifie « il s'agit (de) », « ce qui est en jeu, en cause, c'est ».
>
> Comparez :
>   ***Il en va*** de même pour moi (= il en est de même pour moi). ***Il en va*** tout autrement pour lui (ou *de lui*). On trouve aussi la construction : ***Il en va*** de cette affaire-là comme de l'autre.
>
> *Je ne vous mens pas. **Il y va** de mon honneur* (= il s'agit de mon honneur, mon honneur est en jeu).

[Sur Langue-fr.net](http://www.langue-fr.net/Aller-Il-y-va-de-ou-il-en-va)
Aller : « Il y va de... » ou « il en va de... » ?

> On confond parfois les deux expressions, mais leur sens diffère !
>   **Il en va de**... : ce en renvoie à une comparaison ou à un exemple (en indique que le cheminement est le même).
>
> **Il y va de**... annonce ce qui est en jeu.

[TERMIUM Plus](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=9iW9JzAAdfFU.html) :

**il y va de/il en va de**

> Les constructions impersonnelles avec le verbe aller sont considérées comme littéraires par certains auteurs.
>
> **Il y va de**
>   À la forme impersonnelle, au sens d’« être en jeu », d’« il s’agit de », de « ce qui est en cause/en jeu, c’est… », l’expression consacrée est **y aller de** suivi d’un substantif.
>
> - Il y va de l’honneur de notre famille.
> - Elle a dû réfléchir longuement à ces études, car il y allait de son avenir.
>
> **Il en va de**
>
> Le tour **il en va** est correct dans les expressions suivantes :
>
> - il en va (tout) autrement pour/de + nom de personne ( elle, lui, toi, etc.)
> - il en va de même pour/de
> - il en va ainsi pour/de …

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Donc ces journalistes ne sont pas très forts en français s'ils prennent une expression pour l'autre, non?

Comment: @user26328 Disons qu'on s'attend à autre chose de la part du *Monde* ! Je dois dire que je n'étais pas conscient que cette confusion existait avant de lire ta question. Et en cherchant un peu j'ai vu que c'était assez fréquent pour que des articles y soient consacrés.

Comment: Vous croyez que mon français est relativement bon ?

Comment: @Feelew *être conscient de*  dans le TLF :  «Qui a une connaissance immédiate et directe, plus ou moins complète et claire, de quelque chose ». ????? Je ne comprends pas...  mais je suis conscient que je fais souvent des fautes, et je ne les vois pas toujours.

Comment: @Feelew Mais les pseudos ne sont pas genrés !

Comment: @user26328  Si tu n'avais pas posé la question je ne me serais pas douté  que tu n'étais pas francophone (si c'est bien ce qu'implique la question dans ton commentaire).

Answer (score 1):

Word for Word:

> « il  » = as an impersonal subject: "it" or "the situation"
>
> « va » = "goes"
>
> « de même  » = "the same (way)"
>
> « en  » = referring to an element from previous context: "(as) something else"
>
> « pour »  = "for/concerning (something)"

All in All:

> « il en va de même pour ... » or « il en va de même de ... »
>
> = "it goes the same for ... " or "the same can be said for ... "

Comment: The question is not about *il en va de même pour* but *il en va de son intérêt*.

Comment: It's not a good idea to translate by breaking a phrase down into single words, as translation covers meaning and meaning is often not conveyed by translating individual words.

Answer (score 1):

De son côté, la Chine juge qu’il en va de son intérêt stratégique de maintenir en vie cet Etat tampon. '

**For its part, China believes it's in its strategic interest to keep this buffer state alive.**

You could push it and write: believes its strategic interest is on the line

With de même, it means: The same goes for or the same applies to.

This is not at stake in English here from this French expression.

to be at stake is l'enjeu or some verb.

Answer (score 0):

« Il en va de quelque chose » signifie ici que cette chose est en jeu, qu'il existe un risque significatif la menaçant.

Ce n'est pas le bon site pour demander une expression anglaise mais je pense que *is at stake* est assez proche.

> But I thought that "to be at stake" translates into French as *il y va de quelque chose*.

You are correct but that's nevertheless what the author meant in that sentence. Using *en* vs *y* is such a common usage that I didn't even notice the issue while answering on my phone.

If you compare *il en va de son honneur* vs *il y va de son honneur* with a search engine, you'll see it is often not spotted by newspaper's and other media proofreaders. I got 88 "il en va" vs 134 "il y va de son honneur".

[image]
[image]

Even in books, the *en va* form usage is raising in the last decades.

[image]

Comment: But I thought that "to be at stake" translates into French as _il y va de quelque chose_.

Comment: Comment answered in my reply for me to be able to add graphics.