# Dilemma of whether to say "il y va de ma réputation" or "il en va de ma réputation"

Tags: choix-de-mot

In conversation with one of my colleagues, I said jokingly and sarcastically:

> Je ne peux pas toujours être là pour toi, tu sais. Enfin si, ***il y va*** certes ***de*** ma réputation de chevalier blanc, mais ça ne te coûterait rien d’en apprendre toutes les ficelles pour que tu puisses t'en sortir seule, en cas d'*éventuel* pépin...

Later, I discussed with other colleagues the common mix-up between "il y va de qch" and "il en va de qch" with the meaning of "qch est en jeu".

When I had first picked up this expression and posted a related question a year ago when I had just started learning French, I had thought that "il ***en*** va de qch" was the only legitimate expression.

I then went on to find out, however, (according to a similar post) that "il ***y*** va de qch" was actually the correct form.

And as it has now turned out, my colleagues are overwhelmingly in favour of "il ***en*** va de qch". Which has put me back into the vicious circle of uncertainty once  again...

I now wonder if there is a regional difference between the two versions or some factors affect the choice?

Comment: We had a [similar question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25469/358) a few months ago and I would not change my answer. No regional difference as far as I know but just a common misuse.

Comment: @Laure Precisely, that particular answer of yours back then gave me a lot of food for thought to chew on, as well as a headache. ;) All the more reason I wonder why both versions seem to be used almost as frequently  -- not just among my colleagues, but also in many reliable French translations that I have come across in a year.

Comment: It's just a question of language living / evolving. In XX years from now maybe French won't make the difference between the 2. As far as trustworthy dictionaries are concerned it still exists. See the [TLF](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25469/358) for instance, ***Il y va de + nom de chose**. Ce qui est en cause, c'est...*  | ***Il en va de** même (ou ainsi) de (ou pour), il en va (tout) autrement (de ou pour + nom de pers.). La situation est la même ou tout autre (pour telle personne)*

Answer (score 1):

*en* and *y* can usually gramatically be swaped, but they are semantically different.

In contexts where they both mean a change of place, *en* implies that you're coming from whatever place is mentioned while *y* implies it to be your destination.

Example :

- *J'y viens* means *I'm coming **to** it*.
- *J'en viens* means *I'm coming **from** it*.

In your example, *Il* represants the assertion from your previous sentence. Since the purpose of your second sentence is to justify that assertion, your reputation is the justification, **from** which comes that assertion. that **from** relation is already marked by the preposition *de*, while what you are actually describing with the verb *va* is the movement from your repoutation to the conclusion in your previous sentence.

In short, *Il y va de ma réputation de ma réputation que je ne pourrai pas toujours être là.*

But I guess the *en* form imposed itself from its existence in other contexts - *il en va de même* - and a lack of familiarity with the correct form due to its relative rarity.