# What is the meaning of the construction « y aller de » ?

Tags: constructions

Larousse is saying that the definition of ***« y aller de »*** is

***« engager une certaine somme ; produire quelque chose comme contribution. (→ allez !, allons !, va !.) ».***

I don’t understand this definition. Therefore could someone provide me with an explanations and some example sentences please.

Please bear in mind that my level in french is **beginner** thus could you make any explanation as simple as possible. Thank you!

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/aller/2359?q=Aller#2362

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This definition is slightly confusing, even for a native speaker.

A better clue can be found by looking to the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aller) that says:

> *Fam. Y aller de qqc.* Entreprendre une certaine action :
> 35. Lacretelle me disait : « ***Allez**-y ! Nommez-vous. **Allez**-y d'une dédicace...* » A. Gide, Journal, 1930, p. 966.

where *y aller de* is used at the imperative: *allez-y de...*

The meaning is close to "go for it", "go ahead and do it".

Here are examples matching the definitions given by the Larousse:

1. engager une certaine somme :

> *J'y vais de 5 francs !* → I'm betting 5 Francs on it. (outdated)

2. produire quelque chose comme contribution :

> *Il y va encore de son discours habituel* → He brings us again his usual speech.

Note that there is another *y aller de* expression that is not informal and shouldn't be confused with the one just mentioned, e.g. *Il y va de mon honneur*. With that second expression, the pronoun *il* is impersonal. It doesn't represent anything/anyone. Both other replies so far are partially or totally about that other phrase.

See [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25469/quel-est-le-sens-de-il-en-va) for its frequent confusion with *en aller de*.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!  I have a few questions that I hoping you could answer.

Comment: (1) What is the meaning of « Il y va de mon honneur ». ? Does it mean “Your honour is at stake.” just like how « Il y va de votre intérêt. » means “your best interest is at stake.”

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: Thank you!  (2) I don’t understand what your talking about when you say “Both other replies so far are partially or totally about that other phrase.”

Comment: I mean Ouch42's reply is not about the expression you are looking for and Yagmoth555's one has just one example spot on. I added comments to both of these replies to state it. LPH's answer came later. As often, it is a mixture of correct things, unrelated things and possibly "invented French". Searching two of his examples lead to single Google hits, his answer...

Comment: Thank you for clearing the fog. :) I didn’t know people answered with “invented french” :/. Which example is invented french? and was it one of LPH’s examples only had only Google hit or one of Yagmoth555 ?

Comment: (3) Thank you so much for the two example sentences that you provided. Could you please see if I used the 2 meanings of « Il y va de » correctly please? 

Comment: (Scenario 1) Adam: How much are you investing? 
Jake: I’m investing/commting £1,000,000. I will invest/commit my house if I have to.

Comment: (Scénario 1) Adam: Combien  investis-tu ?
Jake: J’y va de 1,000,000 €. J’y irai de ma maison si je dois.

Comment: I was referring to LPH. Your example is slightly odd because *combien investis-tu ?* is very formal while *y aller de* is both informal and above all outdated when talking about money (outside idioms like *y aller de sa poche*). That's the reason why in my examples I chose Francs instead of Euros :-) It's difficult to write something convincing here. In any case, that would be *J'y **vais** **d'un million d'euros***.

Comment: Thank you @jlliagre !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115294/discussion-between-noybwbh-and-jlliagre).

Answer (score 4):

**I** *Contribution*

The most common expresssion using that phrase might perhaps  be "**y aller de sa/leur/notre/… poche**" .

- (fixed phrase) Il a dû y aller de **sa poche** et a réglé l'addition. → *He had to stump up for the check.*
- (fixed phrase) D'habitude ils **y vont de leur personne**. → *Usually they take a hand in it themselves.* (Harrap's)
- Il y est allé d'**une bouteille**. → *He stood us a bottle.* (Harrap's)
- Il y va de **ses économies** pour payer les études de son fils. → *He sacrifices his savings to pay for his son's studies.* (Harrap's)

An indefinite number of sentences can be produced by using other noun phrases or expressions than "une bouteille", "ses économies"  30 euros, un bouquet de fleurs, etc.

**II** *Drive, Energy*

Nevertheless, "y aller de" is not only used for meanings implying a contribution. Another  important context is that of the manner of engaging oneself into an action, an activity. A first common expression is "**y aller de tout son cœur**".

- (fixed phrase) Il y est allé de tout son cœur. → *He put his whole heart into it.* (Harrap's)

Another one is "**y aller de toutes ses/sa force(s)**".  (Harrap's)

- Il y est allé de toute ses forces. → *He went at it for all he was worth.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115353/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-construction--y-aller-de).

Answer (score 3):

It can indicate the consequence of not doing something, too.

Like in : "Portez un masque! Il y va de la vie des plus fragiles".

It is then equivalent to "to be at stake", as I understand it.

EDIT : As pointed by jlliagre, the use of "y aller de" in my answer doesn't match the definition from the OP question.
Regarding that definition, I have to say that I find it unclear, even being a native french speaker.

Comment: That's a different *y aller de*.

Comment: You are right. But I think that knowing the different meanings is usefull for people learning french, for instance.

Comment: Indeed, but you might want to make that clearer in your reply as the question states: *I don’t understand **this** definition.*

Comment: It is done. Thank you for pointing out this subtle but real difference.

Comment: Isn't this "EN aller de" and not "Y aller de" ?

Comment: No, "en aller de" et "y aller de" are different.
See http://www.academie-francaise.fr/il-en-va-de-pour-il-y-va-de#:~:text=Ce%20n'est%20pas%20le,va%20de%20m%C3%AAme%20des%20avions for instance.

Comment: @jlliagre Is Ouch42’s definition an outdated? Is it formal also?

Comment: It is a formal/literary expression. It can still be used.

Comment: @Ouch42 Thank you for your help!!!!! 

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you for telling me this!!!!